# Join object of individual characters

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to convert an object containing individual, indexed characters into a single string however I cannot use the join method seeing as this is an object rather than an array. Is there a method available for this? I know how to manually iterate through the objects key-value pairs though I'd rather use an existing method if possible. Here is the data I'm working with

```
{0: "R",
1: "E",
2: "G",
3: "U",
4: "L",
5: "A",
6: "R"}
```

and I would like to return

```
"REGULAR"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const chars = {0: "R",
1: "E",
2: "G",
3: "U",
4: "L",
5: "A",
6: "R"}

Object.values(chars).join('');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much!

Comment: it's my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do it in the following way:-

```js
const object = {0: "R",
1: "E",
2: "G",
3: "U",
4: "L",
5: "A",
6: "R"}

const objectString = Object.values(object).join('');
console.log(objectString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
  0: "R",
  1: "E",
  2: "G",
  3: "U",
  4: "L",
  5: "A",
  6: "R"
}

const newData = Object.values(data).join("")
```

You first need to transform the object to an array with the values of the object, `Object.values` does that and then simply use the `join` function with the empty string paratemeter to create an string from the array.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `for` loop can go over all the numeric keys in sequence and stop when the sequence ends. You can collect the values for those keys in a string:

```js
const obj = { 0: "R", 1: "E", 2: "G", 3: "U", 4: "L", 5: "A", 6: "R" };

let result = "";
for (let i = 0; i in obj; i++) {
  result += obj[i];
}

console.log(result);
```

This approach can be leveraged to create [a generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) that produces the values.

```js
function* valuesInSequence(obj) {
  for (let i = 0; i in obj; i++) {
    yield obj[i];
  }
}

const obj = { 0: "R", 1: "E", 2: "G", 3: "U", 4: "L", 5: "A", 6: "R" };

let result = "".concat(...valuesInSequence(obj));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I know how to iterate through the object but was looking for a function to do that for me but thank you